# Mathematica CSV values

Tags: list-manipulation, import, numerical-value

I wanted just to add constant to each value. i. e.

```
data = Import["/Users/paul/Desktop/rtm1.csv", "CSV"]
```

And I get

```
{{2.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {4.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {6.*10^-9, 
  0.0025}, {8.*10^-9, 0.0025}, {1.*10^-8, 0.0025},...}
```

I wanted to add -0.0025 and get

```
{{2.*10^-9, 0}, {4.*10^-9, 0}, {6.*10^-9, 
  0}, {8.*10^-9, 0}, {1.*10^-8, 0},...}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Try `{#[[1]],#[[2]]-0.0025}&/@data`

Comment: @bobthechemist It works fine, thanks.

Comment: To explain how that amazing little piece of code works, the code uses the `Map[ ]` or `/@` function to apply a function to every element in the list `data`. But each element is a list with two members, which get treated by the function `Function[{x,y-.25}]` or `{x,y-.25}&`. But the function uses `Part[ ]` to replace x with the first element in the list and y with the second (`#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]`). Beautiful!